# Expressing $\sin\pi/n$ in terms of radicals of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, trigonometry

Are values of $$\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$ where $n$ is a positive integer all expressible in terms of radicals of integers?

If not, what is the first $n$ for which it is not?

Comment: Not all. One example is $n=7$. See here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi7.html

Comment: Well, they are all expressible in terms of roots of $1$, but something tells me you may not appreciate such an answer. Even when they are solutions of cubic equations with radical coefficients ($n=7,9$) I don't immediately see a way of writing them using **real** roots of integers only.

Comment: @Potato, that is wrong. That the heptagon isn't constructible means that there is no finite expression in terms of _square_ roots giving $\sin \pi / 7$, not that it can't be expressed as other roots. The doubling of the cube isn't constructible either, and it just involves $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Turn it around: By the known trigonometric identities you can express $\sin n \alpha$ in terms of a polynomial in $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$, which gives you a polynomial equation in $\sin \alpha$ if you know $\sin n \alpha$. Now you want to know if that equation is solvable by radicals.

Comment: @vonbrand My link concerns taking roots of any degree of real numbers.

Comment: @Potato, that doesn't make the link you provide any less wrong. Look up constructible numbers. With straightedge and compass only _square_ roots can be taken directly. If $\sin \pi / 7$ involved taking a cubic root, the heptagon wouldn't be constructible.

Comment: @vonbrand The heptagon is not constructible. I don't understand your objection.

Comment: @vonbrand and Potato: In the case of the real and imaginary parts of roots of unity, it is known that they are constructible if and only if they can be expressed using only real radicals. For a proof, see Andrzej W. Mostowski, [*Un théorème sur les nombres* $\cos 2{\pi}k/n$](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm1/cm132.pdf), Colloquium Mathematicae 1 (1948), 195-196. For more about real radical numbers, see my [26 September 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3977641).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate polynomials for such sines and cosines by considering

$$\sin{\frac{n \pi}{2 n+1}}= \sin{\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2 n+1}}$$

With $n=2$ ($\pi/5$) we get a quadratic, $n=3$ ($\pi/7$) a cubic, and so forth.  It would seem to me that $\pi/11$ would be the first one which can't be expressed in terms of radicals of rationals.

Comment: Unfortunately the value of $\cos \pi/7$ (and hence of $\sin \pi/7$) (as given in Mathematica or Maple) involves cube root of some complex numbers.

Comment: @TCL: that is irrelevant to my point, inconvenient as it may be.  My point is that at $\pi/11$ you get a $5th$ degree polynomial, which is insoluble in principle in terms of such roots.

Comment: But not all fifth degree polynomials are in principle insoluble, only the general fifth degree. For any particular quintic one has to look at the polyomial itself to decide solubility by radicals.

Comment: Yes, we need to careful here. There are many 7th and 11th degree polynomials that are solvable in roots, and even integer roots.

Comment: Galois theory doesn't really help here: in fact, the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\pi/11)) = \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/11))$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $C_5$ which is obviously solvable.  But since the theory implicitly assumes that roots of unity are "uninteresting" all that really says is that $\cos(\pi/11)$ can be expressed in terms of radicals over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$.  Which is trivial since $\cos(\pi/11)$ is already in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$.